# Oracle V.11 Rolling Year

Tags: oracle

How to query a rolling year of data?

Below is what I have so far, but it is not working, help would be appreciated.

```
WHERE 1=1 AND TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(A.START_DT,-12),'DD-MON-YYYY') "Rolling Year"
```

Comment: you are not comparing it with the column start_dt ?

Comment: That's what I would like to do. I'm not sure if I have the syntax correct.

Comment: you can just do where a.start_dt>=ADD_MONTHS(A.START_DT,-12)

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I looking for the past 12 months of data from today's date. I'm getting back results from 2012 when I run your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?:

```
WHERE START_DT BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12) AND SYSDATE
```

If START_DT doesn't have any times other than midnight (e.g. 2016-06-17 00:00:00) you may want this instead:

```
WHERE START_DT BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -12) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```